# Determining URL of script that is calling from a remote CURL request

Tags: php, curl

I have a homebase script, that I have many other scripts ping for information using the CURL method. I need to determine the domain name of the callers. Can I do this with tricks just on my homebase script?

. using php .

Hudson

Answer (score 0):

You could send a custom HTTP header with your CURL request that contains the script name, something like

```
X-SCRIPT-NAME myscript.php
```

I don't think CURL automatically adds something about the calling script, so you would have to edit the scripts for this.